# what is the difference between standard and basic version of Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Database for storing of my company record. But they are charging really more and it is very expensive. I am using SQL Database Standard edition, so I thought I can move on to basic edition to minimize the expenses. What is the difference between standard and basic edition. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Standard & Basic edition of what service? There are many services in Azure.

Comment: @GauravMantri : SQL database

Comment: Please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/sql-database/ which compares various editions.

Comment: @GauravMantri : thank u very much bro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at this comparison between tiers:

[Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/?rnd=1)

[image]

The main information is the DTU (Database Throughput Unit) that allows you to compare tiers.

As of today (10/2015), prices are:

```
B: $0.0067/hr (~$5/mo)

S0: $0.0202/hr (~$15/mo)
S1: $0.0403/hr (~$30/mo)
S2: $0.1008/hr (~$75/mo)
S3: $0.2016/hr (~$150/mo)

P1: $0.625/hr (~$465/mo)
P2: $1.25/hr (~$930/mo)
P4: $2.50/hr (~$1,860/mo)
P6: $5/hr (~$3,720/mo)
P11:$9.41/hr (~$7,001/mo)
```

[Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/)

Comment: Can u please provide detail about price??

Comment: Just a side note if you're super worried about pricing on the low end. If you take a DB from Basic to S0 you can't go back to Basic. That's $5 vs $15 so it's not a big deal on a single DB to a company but might be a big deal for 20 DBs or a personal project.

Answer (score 0):

For low and middle performance databases the prices are skyrocketing. Going from web to basic explode costs if you have many small databases as I have

That's inacceptable.

The switch to new pricing tiers is in my opinion is a scam. Time to switch to other providers!

Also look here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/6848339-please-reconsider-the-new-db-pricing-tiers